# Is it rational to compare vegetation indices derived from different Landsat sensors?

Tags: raster, ndvi, landsat-8

I am using images from two different sensors, Landsat 8 OLI (January 2017) and ETM+ (January 2007) to compute various vegetation indices.

These indices involve RED and NIR band to scale vegetation density and intensity. I have noticed the difference in wavelengths of both sensors’ required bands as follows;

*Wavelength (micrometers)*

**Landsat 7 ETM+**

Band 3 – Red            :   0.63-0.69

Band 4 – Near Infrared (NIR)    :   0.77-0.90

**Landsat 8 OLI**

Band 4 – Red            :   0.64-0.67

Band 5 – Near Infrared (NIR)    :   0.85-0.88

See Reference https://landsat.usgs.gov/what-are-band-designations-landsat-satellites

Keeping in view this wavelength difference of both sensors' RED & NIR Bands, I am interested to know whether this difference will affect my intended results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question really is a bit too large for a post here, but thankfully, the research has already been done (multiple times) and the conclusion is usually something along the lines of:

> The  difference  of  vegetation  indices  comparison  showed  that  there  were  subtle  differences  between  both  sensors,  which  demonstrated  high  similarity.  LSWI,  NBR  and  NDVI  had  average  difference  values  less  than  ±0.05  and  a  smaller  standard  deviation.

And goes on to state:

> Additionally, correlation analysis  of  the  vegetation  indices  indicated  that  both  sensors  had  a  very  high  linear  correlation  coefficient, with R2 greater than 0.96. The subtle differences and high correlation of vegetation indices demonstrated  that  ETM+  and  OLI  imagery  can  be  used  as  complementary  data.

Source: http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/6/1/310/pdf